# Unless invited, he won't attend the show

Tags: grammar

"Unless getting invitation, he won't attend the show." Is this sentence correct? How to omit the adverbial clauses of condition in a sentence?

Comment: Which is your actual question? The one in the title or the one in the body of the question?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is incorrect, even though it can be understood.  The reason is not altogether clear.  However, it has nothing to do with adverbial conditional clauses (whatever they are).  The obvious and simple expression is:

> Unless he gets a ticket, he won’t attend the show.

This is a simple conditional sentence, with a protasis, introduced by the subordinating conjunction ‘unless’, followed by the main clause protasis.  Protasis and apodosis could be written in the opposite order without changing the meaning.

If you want, for some reason, to avoid having a subordinate clause, you could use an adverbial phrase ‘without getting a ticket’, or, better still, ‘without a ticket’.  The adverbial phrase sits better after the main clause than before it:

> He won’t attend the show without (getting) a ticket.
>
> or just He won’t attend the show without a ticket.

Or you can say these things the other way round.

In at least one dialect of English, descended from Yiddish, you can even say:

> Without he gets a ticket, he won’t attend the show.

Answer (score 1):

**unless invited**

K. Izzo & C. Marsh *Fabulous Girl's Guide to Decorum* (2002)    Never send scripts, showreels or audio cassettes **unless invited** to do so.

Your sentence modified:

> "Unless invited, he won't attend the show."